# Kendo grid batch edit

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid in batch editing mode. When I click on add new row, it triggers a create event and when I edit a row , it triggers an update event. This is all good and it is as per documentation.

But My requirement is as such When I click on "add new row" it should trigger an update event instead of create event is that possible ?

What I am trying to do is , since it is batch save. So even a new row added should be treated like modifying a row. So for example if I do the following

(1) Add a new row

(2) modify an existing row

On clicking save changes button, it should trigger a update action and 2 objects should be sent to server for update . Please let me know if it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you want is [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing). I've used it before, it's so simple and easy.